# Dataflow column Camel case

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using `initCap(regexReplace($$,' ',''))` to remove spaces form my columns and capitalise the first character but is there a way camel case this?

example

Greater than ten = GreaterThanTen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace(initCap('Greater than ten'),' ','')